# How to get the current page request parameters behind method in cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to create method to get the eventstarget of each page use my methods of class

```
private static string sample()
{
    return Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried having a look at this similar forum post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1751514.aspx/1

Comment: yes but dosent explain my problem , later i impelented methods to get postback controls but now accures some bug at diffrent conditions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you need to use the HttpContext which is part of the system.web namespace. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i fix my proble with this `HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];`
but another  problem is cant use find control of page at current page like this 
i created this method to get button control when null  returned i know but at some condition not working correctly

```
private  string getPostBackControlID()
    {
        Control control = null;
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

        if (page != null)
        {
            string ctrlname = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
            if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != String.Empty)
            {
                control = page.FindControl(ctrlname);
            }
            else
            {
                string ctrlStr = String.Empty;
                Control c = null;
                foreach (string ctl in HttpContext.Current.Request.Form)
                {
                    if (ctl != null)
                    {

                        if (ctl.EndsWith(".x") || ctl.EndsWith(".y"))
                        {
                            ctrlStr = ctl.Substring(0, ctl.Length - 2);
                            c = page.FindControl(ctrlStr);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            c = page.FindControl(ctl);
                        }
                        if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button ||
                                 c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)
                        {
                            control = c;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (control != null)
            {
                return control.ID;
            }
            else
                return "";
        }
        return "";

    }
```

Comment: Its really a bad practice to use return ""; why now return String.empty ??? or return null

Comment: if return string empty i know some error accures and dosent goto next step

Answer (score 0):

You can find page with like this

```
  Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

    if (page != null)
    {
       // Use page instance.
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: after add refrence i can test and get null result friend

Comment: what is null? page or control ? can you paste your code pleaes

Comment: Complete code please and not the method ,  i am interested in namespace as well

Comment: i need return control id behind a user control and no more my friend